# Why can't I see any transparency on my material with Eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

This feels like such a basic question, but I can't work it out.  I need to render a semi transparent Lego block and see the back faces of the block.

[image]

I'm using Eevee in Blender 2.8 and have created a Principled BDSF texture with a mix shader and a Transparent BDSF.  I'm passing an RGB node with black colour (I tried white too) into the Transparency BDSF. I am seeing transparency, but I can't see the back faces and cant find an option for 2 sided material or mesh in this version of blender.

[image]

How do I do this please?

Comment: Besides what Andrey already stated in his answer, your transparent node has a solid black color, which essentially makes it opaque.

Comment: Thank you.  That's also very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all with Principled BSDF you don't have to mix it with Transparent because it already has its own transparency mixer, Alpha slider. The second - in material tab in settings make sure your Blend mode is 'Alpha Blend' and 'Show Backface' is enabled.

**UPD.** 'Show Backface' option indeed shows the back sides of the polygons but simultaneously stops to show the front sides. I guess in some cases it can be used as a kind of fake semi-transparency, but in fact it is not.
[image: example]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was after.  Problem solved.